# Are tensor dimensions row x column just like matrices?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following this [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/get_started/mnist/beginners).

This is a basic question but I want to make sure I fully understand it. Are tensor dimensions described as row x column.

In this line:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
```

Does this mean that there are 784 columns and any number of rows?

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/get_started/mnist/beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rank 2 tensor is equivalent to a matrix in tensorflow, and the rows and columns can be thought of in the way that you have described. A typical use case for the `None` value for a dimension is to allow for a variable number of examples. In your case, `x` would be well-suited to holding any number of examples, each of which have 784 feature values.

Comment: a rank 1 tensor is equivalent to a vector. Is it always a column vector?

Comment: It shouldn't be thought of as either. A rank 1 tensor with `shape = [N]` is a different creature than a rank 2 tensor with `shape = [1,N]` (what you might call a row vector) or a rank 2 tensor with `shape = [N,1]` (what you might call a column vector).

Answer (score 1):

A `Tensor` can loosely be seen as an `n`-dimensional vector.

Hence,

- tf.placeholder(tf.float32) => a scalar.
- tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3]) => a Vector.
- tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]) => a matrix (rows, columns).
- tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 3]) => a 3-Tensor (batch_size, row, columns, channels).

`None` means the Tensor can receive an arbitrary number.